# how to convert multiple columns of data into one column in DolphinDB?

Tags: unpivot, dolphindb

I have a table like as this, it means the number of products owned by each company

```
productType   company1    company2    company3
----------    --------    --------    --------
a             4           1           3
b             5           2           23
c             1           3           4
d             2           4           5
```

How can I get a table like following:

```
producType    companyName    amount
----------    -----------    ------
a             company1       4    
b             company1       5    
c             company1       1   
d             company1       2  
a             company2       1
b             company2       2
c             company2       3
d             company2       4
a             company3       3
b             company3       23
c             company3       4
d             company3       5
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use function `unpivot` to solve your problem.

```
t = table(`a`b`c`d as productType, 4 5 1 2 as company1, 1 2 3 4 as company2, 3 23 4 5 as company3)
unpivot(t, `productType, `company1`company2`company3)
```